# Как сформировать запрос при помощи curl в PHP?

Tags: php, curl

В документации к API сказано, что в тело запроса нужно вставить JSON-строку с параметрами и указан пример:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"signature":"deb5b02159898a6ab6f120624fa2f72c","marker":"ВставьтеСюдаВашМаркер","host":"beta.aviasales.ru","user_ip":"127.0.0.1","locale":"ru","trip_class":"Y","passengers":{"adults":1,"children":0,"infants":0},"segments":[{"origin":"NYC","destination":"LAX","date":"2016-11-25"},{"origin":"LAX","destination":"NYC","date":"2016-12-18"}]}' -H 'Content-type:application/json' http://api.travelpayouts.com/v1/flight_search
```

А как можно вставить json-массив в тело запроса при использовании cURL в PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно установить опции `CURLOPT_POST` на `1` и в `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` отправить ваши переменные:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$post_data = array (  
    "foo" => "bar",  
    "query" => "12",  
    "action" => "Submit"  
);  

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
```

Json можно декодировать с помощью [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php). Данные в этом формате не проходят (подойдет только `key=value&key1=value1` или массив)